# Certificate for AddSigningCredential

Tags: identityserver4

I am new in IdentityServer4 and trying to create JSON Web token. For development I have used AddDeveloperSigningCredential but for other environments I need to use AddSigningCredential but I do not know how to get certificate. I don't have any certificate actually and not sure how can I generate it? Can anyone provide some inputs how to generate certificate and use with AddSigningCredential and then after creation of token, how can I validate token using same certificate in API

After generation of certificate as described in comments. I have added following code

Code in identity server

services.AddIdentityServer() .AddAspNetIdentity() .AddConfigurationStore(options => { options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)); }) .AddOperationalStore(options => { options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)); }) .AddSigningCredential(certificate);

Code in API

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddJwtBearer(options => { options.Authority = "localhost:44339"; });

Issuer is

{"issuer":"localhost:44339","jwks_uri":"https://…" I have fetched this information from
https://localhost:44339/.well-known/openid-configuration

I am getting 401 error in postman and getting error is WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'policyservice' is invalid"

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted it. By adding Audience, authentication is successful. For Authorization failure, I have created another thread. Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551279/jwt-authorization-with-identityserver4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any tool that can generate a private/public key pair.

In the example below I use openssl.

First we create a RSA private key:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -aes256 -out rsa-private-key.pem
```

Then you can create a certificate using :

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key rsa-private-key.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=MyRSACert" -out rsa-cert.crt
```

Then you can package up the cert and private key into a .pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey rsa-private-key.pem -in rsa-cert.crt -out rsa.pfx
```

Then in code you can load the cert using:

```
var rsaCert = new X509Certificate2("rs256.pfx", "yourpassword");
```

Then to add it to IdentityServer you can use:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
     ...
    .AddSigningCredential(rsaCert)
```

Comment: What should I put in "your password". Is it a new password which I am going to create first time or getting from somewhere

Comment: when you run the openssl command it will ask for a password as a protection

Comment: And, can you please share inputs on how to use same certificate in API which I am protecting

Comment: Actually my last question was how this token will be validated in WebAPI using same certificate? I think you mentioned about Identity server but I was talking about WebAPI which I am trying to protect using Identity server

Comment: The WebAPI (using AddJwtBearer) will automatically download the public key from IdentityServer and then use it to validate all the incoming tokens. The certificate is only used to "transport" the private key. In the past it was easier to work with certificates in .NET than raw keys, I know its better supported in .NET 6.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: I am using .net 6. If I don't mention certificate in webapi then AddJwtBearer will everytime go to Identity server to validate it. Is it good practice to go to Identity server everytime for each API request? I am not sure about it. Is it possible to use certificate in webapi to validate the token?

Comment: Wit AddJwtBearer, you do not need to add the keys/certificate manually in the API, AddJwtBearer  will download the keys and remember them, so there is not a new roundtrip for every incoming request. It is handled 100% automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: All AddJwtBearer needs is the url to the issuer of the tokens and then it handles he rest. then there are some other options that you can tweak.

Comment: For example here, the AddJwtBearer will first download https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration and then download the keys from the JWKS endpoint https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks , that's all!

Comment: So it is one time activity to download the keys from JWKS endpoint once API starts or we make it up and running for first time. Is it correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, then by default the keys are refreshed every 24hours.

Comment: Code  in identity server services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddSigningCredential(certificate);

Comment: Code in API
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44339";
            });
Issue is 
{"issuer":"https://localhost:44339","jwks_uri":"https://localhost:44339/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks"

I have fetched this information from

I am getting 401 error in postman and getting error is 
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'policyservice' is invalid"

Comment: Better to add code to the question instead of in the comments, what is the question?

Comment: I have added code in question now. Can you please check once

Comment: After passing Audience as policyservice, it is getting authenticated but authorization is getting failed. Getting 403 error in postman. I have placed Authorize attribute on top of API controller action method as I have included Role based authorization. If I am removing Authorize attribute, it is working fine . I have already added  Role in claims in Identity Server. I have added code for authorization in Question itself