# JWT Authorization with IdentityServer4

Tags: authorization

I am getting Authorization error in postman which using JWT token. Please find below details

Code in identity server

services.AddIdentityServer() .AddAspNetIdentity() .AddConfigurationStore(options => { options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)); }) .AddOperationalStore(options => { options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)); }) .AddSigningCredential(certificate);

Code in API

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddJwtBearer(options => { options.Authority = "localhost:44339"; });

Token generated is :

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgyRTlFNTUwRkY4MTM2ODRDRDRFRjNEQ0MyMzVBMjQyMTZFNkU1Q0NSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImF0K2p3dCIsIng1dCI6Imd1bmxVUC1CTm9UTlR2UGN3aldpUWhibTVjdyJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2NDEwNjMzMTYsImV4cCI6MTY0MTA2NjkxNiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMzkiLCJhdWQiOiJwb2xpY3lzZXJ2aWNlIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoieWNvbXBhbnlhbmd1bGFyY2xpZW50Iiwic3ViIjoiYzk2OTNjMTUtYzU4OS00OGE4LThjMDctYjE1ODQzODMwNjMzIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjQxMDYzMjkwLCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsIlVzZXJJRCI6ImM5NjkzYzE1LWM1ODktNDhhOC04YzA3LWIxNTg0MzgzMDYzMyIsIlJvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImp0aSI6IjYxRTU1RTg2OTZGMURDRUE2QjJFNUNDREUyMjgwQzkwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQxMDYzMzE2LCJzY29wZSI6WyJwb2xpY3lzZXJ2aWNlc2NvcGUiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.e8Uj7P6RCv0ZY0Fg-xeZT558uCJhyyvY0SbOsiFNSJYeDxJ42jK4b_pOG90kMRKHI_ENIbMllHizbAOWetJhWxFLzApP_qCmvKIs1CJNiE8g5B9XH5l3lWsmIDnfgVLu98KLjKOg7F0gVMVyq4NooNVD1DKcmflddBHzGtN4QD3kzOhHPcL4EeJHq7dxL_y6t-AUYD4oDeAf_kGtv-XLaVIyyahqUdJykEguG8GG7A0RKzHSlVSFsBQzMoBSsp-KvhAutKcfK53bACgZLQ2jlMBFLSofCuCBdwrStKFss6yPtq2qQqhh-bOa22bgGlcF_wjzlvHUO96CDHkLKOz-9A

It contains Role as well.

Code for API Controller

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

[image: Authorization Failed in Postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the answer.

I changed `new Claim("Role","Admin")` to `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).