IdentityServer4 Cert AddSigning Credentials
I need some clarification, on the AddSigningCredentials(cert). I know it's recommended for Prod to have use that extension method. The certificate that can be used there, can it be self-generated or does it require a valid certificate?
I have generated my own certificate but now I want to go to prod. Hence I need to know if I can continue to use the self-generated certificate in prod?

it looks like a duplicate of this below question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547314/certificate-for-addsigningcredential
