How to use an RSA key for Duende Identity Server v7
My thought process was:

Create the RSA key in Azure Key Vault --> Keys
Retrieve the key using KeyClient
Pass the key to AddSigningCredential

Here is the C# code
string keyVaultUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSettings:KeyVaultUrl");
var identityServerConfig = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Key");
string keyName = identityServerConfig["Name"];
var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());

KeyVaultKey keyVaultKey = client.GetKey(keyName);

// Ensure the key is an RSA key
if (keyVaultKey.KeyType != KeyType.Rsa && keyVaultKey.KeyType != KeyType.RsaHsm) {
  throw new InvalidOperationException("The key retrieved from Key Vault is not an RSA key.");
}

// Convert KeyVault's RSA key to RsaSecurityKey
var rsa = new RSAParameters { Modulus = keyVaultKey.Key.N, Exponent = keyVaultKey.Key.E };

var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = RSA.Create();
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(rsa);

RsaSecurityKey key = new(rsaCryptoServiceProvider);
identityServiceBuild.AddSigningCredential(key, IdentityServerConstants.RsaSigningAlgorithm.RS256);

Here is the RSA Key creation inside Azure Key Vault

Here is the exception thrown :(
[01:51:18 Information] UnhandledExceptionEvent { Details: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unknown error (0xc100000d)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.TrySignHash(ReadOnlySpan`1 hash, Span`1 destination, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.TrySignData(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.SignUsingSpanRsa(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.SignUsingSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.Sign(ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Span`1 signature, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateSignature(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, Int32& bytesWritten)

I have also tried generating an RSA key using Putty Key Generator and uploading that but same exception is thrown.
Refer to cert in C# like this @Tore?
string keyVaultUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSettings:KeyVaultUrl");
var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());

KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = client.GetCertificate("duendeidentityserverv7");

if (certificate == null) {
  throw new InvalidOperationException($"Certificate duendeidentityserverv7 not found in Azure Key Vault.");
}

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);

identityServiceBuild.AddSigningCredential(cert);


The CryptographicException suggests an issue with the RSA key or its usage in the signing process. Ensure that the key from Azure Key Vault is correctly imported and is compatible with the RS256 signing algorithm. Additionally, verify that the RSA key is properly formatted (modulus and exponent) and supports the required signature padding.

I created the RSA key in the Azure portal so not sure how it could have an issue?

I have seen this problem before and when you get the key, you only get the public key, not the private key. to get the private key, you need to get it as a secret. When I have stored keys in AKV, I have uploaded and stored them as a certificate instead of a raw key and when you try to get the certifictate, you only get the public key and not the private key. So perhaps you see the same problem?
Below is the code I wrote for a few years ago to download the key from Azure Key Vault (key stored as a certificate)
namespace Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods and helper methods to access the Azure Key Vault
    /// 
    /// Written by Tore Nestenius, https://tn-data.se , https://nestenius.se
    /// </summary>
    public static class KeyVaultExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add Azure Key vault to the ASP.NET Configuration system
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        public static void AddAzureKeyVaultSupport(this IConfigurationBuilder config)
        {
            var builtConfig = config.Build();

            string vaultUrl = builtConfig["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
            string clientId = builtConfig["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
            string tenantId = builtConfig["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
            string secret = builtConfig["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

            Console.WriteLine("Adding AzureKeyVault Support");

            CheckIfValueIsProvided(vaultUrl, nameof(vaultUrl), sensitiveValue: false);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(clientId, nameof(clientId), sensitiveValue: true);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(tenantId, nameof(tenantId), sensitiveValue: true);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(secret, nameof(secret), sensitiveValue: true);

            config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultUrl), new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, secret));

            Console.WriteLine("- Vault configured");
        }

        private static void CheckIfValueIsProvided(string value, string parameterName, bool sensitiveValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fatal: - {parameterName} not found");
                throw new Exception($"Fatal: {parameterName} not found");
            }
            else
            {
                //To assist troubleshooting in production, we print out the first character for each config value
                if (sensitiveValue)
                    Console.WriteLine($"- {parameterName}: {value.Substring(0, 1)}...");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"- {parameterName}: {value}");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Load a certificate (with private key) from Azure Key Vault
        ///
        /// Getting a certificate with private key is a bit of a pain, but the code below solves it.
        /// 
        /// Get the private key for Key Vault certificate
        /// https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert
        /// 
        /// See also these GitHub issues: 
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12742
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12083
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(IConfiguration config, string certificateName)
        {
            string vaultUrl = config["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
            string clientId = config["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
            string tenantId = config["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
            string secret = config["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

            Console.WriteLine($"Loading certificate '{certificateName}' from Azure Key Vault");

            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
            var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);

            var cert = GetCertificateAsync(certClient, secretClient, certificateName);

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate loaded");
            return cert;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to get a certificate
        /// 
        /// Source https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert/blob/master/Program.cs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="certificateClient"></param>
        /// <param name="secretClient"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient,
                                                                SecretClient secretClient,
                                                                string certificateName)
        {

            KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);

            // Return a certificate with only the public key if the private key is not exportable.
            if (certificate.Policy?.Exportable != true)
            {
                return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);
            }

            // Parse the secret ID and version to retrieve the private key.
            string[] segments = certificate.SecretId.AbsolutePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (segments.Length != 3)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Number of segments is incorrect: {segments.Length}, URI: {certificate.SecretId}");
            }

            string secretName = segments[1];
            string secretVersion = segments[2];

            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName, secretVersion);

            // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
            // .NET 5.0 preview introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
            if ("application/x-pkcs12".Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
                return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException($"Only PKCS#12 is supported. Found Content-Type: {secret.Properties.ContentType}");
        }
    }
}

In your code, you do this:
       var rsa = new RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = keyVaultKey.Key.N,
            Exponent = keyVaultKey.Key.E
        };

This is only converting the public key, not the private key parts. IdentityServer needs the full private key, not just the public key parts.
You would probably, need to include the other parameters as well, like:
var rsa = new RSAParameters
{
    Modulus = keyVaultKey.Key.N,
    Exponent = keyVaultKey.Key.E,
    D = keyVaultKey.Key.D,           // Private Exponent
    P = keyVaultKey.Key.P,           // First Prime Factor
    Q = keyVaultKey.Key.Q,           // Second Prime Factor
    DP = keyVaultKey.Key.DP,         // First Factor's CRT Exponent
    DQ = keyVaultKey.Key.DQ,         // Second Factor's CRT Exponent
    InverseQ = keyVaultKey.Key.QI    // CRT Coefficient
};

My suggestion is to use OpenSSL to create the keys, using it like this:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -aes256 -out rsa-private-key.pem 

Optionally, if you are curious, you can extract the public key from the above key:
openssl rsa -in rsa-private-key.pem –pubout -out rsa-public-key.pem 

To create a certificate from the private key:
openssl req -new -x509 -key rsa-private-key.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=MyRSACert" -out rsa-cert.crt 


Cheers @Tore
What does key stored as a certificate mean?
I create an RSA key using say Putty Key Generator and I upload it to AKV --> Certificates?
Then what does builtConfig["Vault:ClientSecret"] relate to exactly in AKV? AKV --> Secrets?
At this point I'm so confused.

vaultUrl, clientId tenantId , secret is the access to the vault itself (from the application). That you can do in many different way. Before (in older .NET) working with keys directly was a bit more painfull, it was more easy to store keys in X509Certificate2, however, that is easier today. Also, storing it as X509Certificate2 , allows you to password protect your key inside the certificate. A certificate is just like a wrapper around a key.
In your case, I would compare if the key you receive from Azure Key Vault is the public or private key.  I usually use OpenSSL to create the RSA key.

see my updated answer and the problem in your code.

Cheers @Tore I've been going through these steps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547314/certificate-for-addsigningcredential
So now I have a pfx on my local machine.
I now upload that to AKV --> Certificates?
And then refer to it like I've added in the original question?

Yes, more or less, but do read my initial answer, to ensure that when you download it from AKV, that you also do get the private key part.  This is a good exercise in learning how keys and certificate works :-) Important, as I wrote earlier, today working directly with keys is much easier, than in the past.  :-)

Thanks for your help @Tore
So I create a .pem using openssl
Then I create a .crt from the .pem file using openssl
I then upload .crt that to AKV --> Certificates
Inside your method GetCertificateAsync you use certificateClient to get the
certificate from AKV --> Certificates. FINE.
This is the part I don't follow:
You use secretClient to get a secret? But I haven't uploaded anything to AKV --> Secrets up to this point?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

My code assumes that I have uploaded the cert to AKV manually and I need to get the private key as a secret, because when get the certificate, I only get the public key part.  The secretClient is/was part of the Azure SDK, not sure if there is a different library for that today.

Yes, when you upload the cert to AKV, its a cert, and not visible as a secret, but you can get it as a secret... yes, confusing....
